# Error deploying Tomcat webapp from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, apache-axis, tomcat7

I use to deploy tomcat webapps through eclipse but I have this error:

`WARNING: WebappClassLoader.findClassInternal(myclasspackage) security exception: access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Rnunes\eclipse_indigo_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Service\WEB-INF\classes\myclasspackage\myclass.class read`)

then

```
[INFO] The Service service, which is not valid, caused java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: myclasspackage\myclass.class
```

and then the same for AxisFault$FaultReason

The file path doesn't have any files. Is eclipse missing compilation to those paths? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe. delete all the webapps in the tomcat. check the tomcat is ok or not.
if it's ok, deploy your webapps in the webapps floder. restart the tomcat

about your exceptoins. maybe the the file cannot be reader. all the classes have been compiled when you create the war file or deploy it through eclipse. and the all .class files should be in the WEB-INF/classes . must be here. plz check.
like me :

`\webapps\hlue\WEB-INF\classes\com\ourpalm\hlue\controllers\PassportController.class`

the tomcat just compile jsp file to java.class file on the runtime. and store the temp java .class file to the folder named 'work'. be pleasure to help u .